# using sed to replace pattern with hash values

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed, hashsum

I want to search the file and replace specific pattern with its hash (SHA1) values.

For example, let  `file.txt` has the following content:

`one S56G one two three 

 four five V67X six`

and I want to replace the pattern `[A-Z][0-9]\{2\}[A-Z]` with SHA1 value of the match. In the example above, the matches are `S56G` and `V67X`.

Using `sed`, I tried:

`sed "s/[A-Z][0-9]\{2\}[A-Z]/$(echo \& | sha1sum)/g"`

without success, as the result is always the hash value of `'&'`.

I also tried `ge` flag, with the command:

`sed 's/[A-Z][0-9]\{2\}[A-Z]/echo & | sha1sum/ge'`

which throws errors:

`sh: 1: one: not found


sha1sum: one: No such file or directory


sha1sum: two: No such file or directory


sha1sum: three: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your attempt the command substitution (`$(…)`) is performed *before* `sed` being executed and the string passed to it as parameter.

Use a scripting language which regular expression substitution supports code execution:

```
perl -MDigest::SHA=sha1_hex -pe 's/[A-Z][0-9]{2}[A-Z]/sha1_hex$&/ge' inputfile

php -R 'echo preg_replace("/[A-Z][0-9]{2}[A-Z]/e","sha1(\$0)",$argn),"\n";' inputfile

ruby -rdigest/sha1 -pe '$_.gsub!(/[A-Z][0-9]{2}[A-Z]/){Digest::SHA1.hexdigest$&}' inputfile

python -c 'import sys,fileinput,re,hashlib;[sys.stdout.write(re.sub("[A-Z][0-9]{2}[A-Z]",lambda s:hashlib.sha1(s.group(0)).hexdigest(),l))for l in fileinput.input()]' inputfile
```

Comment: Note that the length of `python` code is not necessarily due to the language's verbosity. Just my knowledge is weaker.

Comment: I still don't understand why my first try (using the 'g' tag) always returns the hash value of '&'. Without the pipe to 'sha1sum', the 'echo' command returns the correct match. Does 'sed' not support redirection?

Comment: @user1734905, see if this is more clear: http://pastebin.com/fvcHTyKV

Answer (score 1):

@manatowork has surely provided with answer. Only adding this as a curiosity ...

A bash+sha1sum variant.

```
function fail()
{
    printf "Failed on line \`%s'\n" "$line" >&2
    exit 2
}

declare -A sha_map;
re='[A-Z][0-9]{2}[A-Z]';

while read -r line; do
    while [[ $line =~ $re ]]; do
        m="${BASH_REMATCH[0]}";
        if ! [[ ${sha_map[$m]} ]]; then
            sha="$(printf "%s" "$m" | sha1sum)" || fail;
            sha_map["$m"]=${sha%% *};
        fi
        line=${line//$m/${sha_map[$m]}};
    done
    printf "%s\n" "$line";
done <"$fn"
```

Comment: I'm quite reluctant writing a script that reads the file line by line. It seems that 'sed' and 'perl', being well designed stream editor, would be able to read the file much more efficiently than a user-written bash script does.

Comment: @user1734905: Indeed. As said, only as a curiosity. And, that said, the approach could be used in a script where the volume is small, and the primary goal (of the script) is another.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my solution:

```
cp file.txt result.txt
cat file.txt | grep -o '[A-Z][0-9]\{2\}[A-Z]' | while read i ; do
    sed -i "s/$i/$(echo -n $i | sha1sum | cut -f 1 -d ' ')/g" result.txt
done
```

Just copy all the lines and paste it into the terminal. With `file.txt`

```
one S56G one two three
four five V67X six
```

I get

```
one 03763566330069a397584344c0a640a3cba05a4c one two three
four five 7802350a2592cdc6dfdee408336919ee9e3cc5f2 six
```

This solution has complexity of O(n^2) and not intended to be used on large files with many pattern matches, since it processes the target file ones per pattern match.

Comment: I see a fast handed member downvoted you without explanation. It could be because 1) possible `openssl` version difference – my `openssl` 1.0.1e provides [messy output](http://pastebin.com/ueL4zBJt); 2) your checksums are calculated including trailing newline, like “S56G\n” – use `echo -n $i|sha1sum` instead.

Comment: @manatwork Thank you! Nice catch :-) I have improved my answer getting ride of openssl and using `echo -n`.

Comment: Your approach has the advantage to easily reduce the amount of hash calculations in case the replaceable fragments are repeated. (So in “a S56G b S56G c S56G d” calculate SHA1 once and replace all 3 occurrences.) Just pipe `grep`'s output through `sort -u` to avoid performing the same calculation again and again. (`sed` will replace them all on the first call anyway.)

Comment: I thought about adding `sort -u`, but then I decided against it. Don't wanted to make it to complicate. The advantage of my approach is, that it's an example of bash scripting: pipe everything together, if performance doesn't matter.